# Google Earth Engine: Add band to Image Collection with mean value in time

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine

I'm working on timeseries with Google Earth Engine. I'm new to GEE and Javascript.
I'm trying to add a band to each image of an image collection with the mean value (**IN TIME**) of another band of the same collection, i.e. a value obtained with **reduce(ee.Reducer.mean())**.
Basically I need to have for every pixel of every image of the collection, the value of a certain band ['B'] and the average value of ['B'] in time.
Even if it sounds quite easy... I'm completely stuck!

Thank you to anyone who can help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var mean = collection.select(['B'], ['B_mean']).mean();

var collectionWithMean = collection.map(function (image) {
  return image.addBands(mean);
});
```

The first step is to take the mean. The form of `select` I'm using here renames the band, which is necessary since it's going to be added back to the same images and so it needs a different name.

(`.mean()` is a shorthand for `.reduce(ee.Reducer.mean())`. You can use either one.)

Then we use `map` on the collection to add the band to each image, and we're done. The images in the collection have bands named `B` and `B_mean`.

Comment: ...it was really that easy! Thank you very much!